# Ajax response inside a table loses access to Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Content loads fine and the page refreshes with dynamic content. However, what's being loaded includes a link to trigger a modal with the appropriate content. Upon clicking on the link, I'm taken to a new page with the content that should be loaded within the modal. Triggering the modal works fine when I don't inject the content via Ajax.

When viewing the source page, I don't see the remote content displayed in the source. I see everything else but the `tbody` within the table/div is empty.

## Page being loaded has this link

```
<a href="/host/{{ $k->hostname }}/log/{{ $k->job_id }}" rel="modal"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><i class="icon-file-text position-left"></i></button></a>
```

## HTML code

```
<div id="refreshme">
    <table>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-info">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h6 class="modal-title" id="sam"></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- /# content goes here -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS code

```
$(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    var environment_id = "{{ $deployment_info->environment_id }}";
    var job_id = "{{ $job_id }}";

    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
    $.get('/deploys/' + environment_id + '/info_div/'+ job_id, function(data) {
        $('#refreshMe tbody').html(data);
    });
}


// Modal code
$('a[rel=modal]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('#modal').modal();
    modal
        .find('.modal-body')
        .load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
            if ( textStatus === 'success' ||
                 textStatus === 'notmodified')
            {
                modal.show();
            }
    });
});
```